# Add many url params in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have to selects that trigger the next functions:

```js
const firstQuery = (value) => {
  history.replace(`${match.path}cars/?car=${value}`);
};

const secondQuery = (value) => {
  history.replace(`${match.path}cars/?color=${value}`);
};
```

When i trigger the first function the url is changing ok: `my-site/cars/?car=audi`, but when i trigger the second one it reset the first value of `?car=audi` and i get `my-site/cars/?color=red`, but my expectation is to get something like: `my-site/cars/?car=audi&color=red` 
How to fix this and to get what i expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

history.replace, replace whole url so you must set your url complete in that

```js
const secondQuery = (value1,value2) => {
  history.replace(`${match.path}cars?car=${value1}&color=${value2}`);
};
```